# How should partial dates hyphened?

Tags: hyphenation, dates

I want to write an abbreviated period of time that goes from 2017 to 2019. I have thought of writing it either as

> 2017-19

or

> 2017 - 19

The difference is in the spacing. Which option is best?

Also, are there better (i.e., more common) options?

Comment: Which option do you think is "best"?

Comment: You could have a look at this, closed as a matter of opinion https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362220/which-format-is-best-for-a-number-range

Answer (score 1):

[As Wikipedia explains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), it is generally considered correct to mark such ranges using *en dashes* (slightly longer than regular hyphens) without spaces. So you would have:

> 2017–19